# Find directories /w files with 2 different extensions

Tags: linux, find, file-extension

So I am trying to think how I can possibly even do this. I can find the files with this for example, but really what I want is the directories specifically that contain both file types. Any ideas?

Also, I don't care what the filename is, just that the directory contains a file /w both extensions.

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.ext1" -or -name "*.ext2" \)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ find . -type f -name "*.ext1" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u; find . -type f -name "*.ext2" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u; } | sort | uniq -d
```

Explanation:

- `find ... -printf "%h\n"` prints directories containing files that match;
- `sort -u` removes duplicates;
- there is `find ... | sort -u` pipe for each of the two extensions;
- the final `sort | uniq -d` prints lines that appear more than once; a directory path will appear more than once iff it is returned by each `find ... | sort -u`.

There are at least two issues:

1. `-printf` is not POSIX. A portable variant of the command may be:

   ```
   { find . -type f -name "*.ext1" | xargs -L 1 dirname | sort -u; find . -type f -name "*.ext2" | xargs -L 1 dirname | sort -u; } | sort | uniq -d
   ```

   `xargs` will complain if `find` finds nothing; this shouldn't break the logic though.
2. Newlines in directory names will break the logic. They can generate false positives, make the output ambiguous. Tools extended beyond their POSIX minimum may support options that allow you to parse null-terminated strings. This works in my Debian:

   ```
   { find . -type f -name "*.ext1" -printf "%h\0" | sort -u; find . -type f -name "*.ext2" -printf "%h\0" | sort -z -u; } | sort -z | uniq -z -d
   ```

   To get a format that is more human-readable, pipe it to `tr '\0' '\n'`. Newlines from directory names will still cause ambiguity but at least multiple lines from a single directory name will appear consecutively, as you surely want them to.

Comment: Awesome response! That is a beyond what I was expecting. Thank you so much.